# Laravel 5.7 : Update method return "No message"

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5.7

I have tried everything and I can't figure out where comes my mistake.

the update() method doesn't update anaything, i only get back "No message" error...

Here's Routes in web.php:

`Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserAdController@edit']);
Route::post('/user/update/{id}', ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' =>'UserAdController@update']);`

the view users/edit.blade.php :

```
<div class="container">
        <br>
        <h3>Edit your ad</h3>
        <br>

        <form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', $ad->id)}}">
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
            {{ method_field('post') }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{$ad->title}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Price</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{$ad->price}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Your content</label>
                <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="content" rows="3">{{$ad->content}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Update method from UserAdController:

```
public function update($id, Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'price'=> 'required|integer',
        'content' => 'required'
    ]);

    $data = \App\Ad::find($id);
    $data->title = $request->get('title');
    $data->price = $request->get('price');
    $data->content = $request->get('content');
    $data->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data updated');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a laravel dev. I just stumbled on the documentation. You should also add the csrf field to your blade

In `edit.blade.php`, add this after the opening `<form>` tag

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Also the parameters in your update method aren't well arranged

It should be

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) { 


}
```

The second parameter(`$id`), comes from what you've defined as your routes in `web.php` file

```
Route::post('/user/update/{id}', ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' =>'UserAdController@update']);
```

Where `{id}` would be replaced by the original `id`

Comment: It's missing some explanations about why `$id` should be on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
public function update(Request $request){
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: *Try this instead* It's missing some explanations about what changes and why.

Answer (score 1):

Request->only() returns an array with one element, While validator is the most common way to handle validation for the incoming request.

```
use Validator;


    public function update(Request $request, $id){


       $v = validator($request->only('title', 'price', 'content'), [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'price' => 'required|integer',
        'content' => 'required',
       ]);

       $data = request()->only('title','price','content');


       $userData = ([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'price' => $data['price'],
        'content' => $data['content'],
       ]);


       $data = \App\Ad::find($id);

       $data->update($userData); 

       return response()->json($data); 

   }
```

Comment: *Try this instead* It's missing some explanations about what changes and why.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all !!

Seems like I wasn't  doing it right.

I needed to add `{{csrf_field()}}` in edit form and use `$request->only()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use put method like this:

```
Route::put('ad/{ad}', ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' =>'UserAdController@update']);
```

update your form to be like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h3>Edit your ad</h3>
    <br>

    <form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', ['ad' => $ad->id])}}">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
        {{ method_field('put') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{$ad->title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Price</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{$ad->price}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Your content</label>
            <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="content" rows="3">{{$ad->content}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info">
        </div>
    </form>
```

and now your update function :

```
public function update(\App\Ad $ad, Request $request){

$request->validate([
    'title'=>'required',
    'price'=> 'required|integer',
    'content' => 'required'
]);

//$data = \App\Ad::find($id);
$ad->update([
   "title" => $request->title,
   "price" => $request->price,
   "content" => $request->content,
]);

return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data updated');

}
```

when you get use to put, delete and patch methods you can read about Route::resource and your code will be easier.